# Flyway - compare checksums

Tags: java, flyway

I am playing about with flyway and I wanted to know if anyone managed to compare the checksums of the applied scripts and classpath scripts, so when updating a script in classpath (dir) I am able to compare the checksum of that with the applied script.

I know flyway.validate() does it but I am looking to add some more info on top of that.

thanks

Comment: What info are you missing from Flyway.validate()?

Answer (score 0):

Flyway.info() will be default return the checksum of the migration on the classpath. You can then compare it to the one present in the metadata table.

Comment: how can i go to get the metatable ? any interfaces available or do i need to extend the flyway class?